# The for loop will only check the value of the first item in the array correctly but not array items at any other index

Tags: c

I'm new to C and trying to write a simple program that will iterate through two arrays to find values in them and then return the index of both values as the index of a 2d array. the problem is, it will not find the value i'm looking for unless its at index zero even though it's in the array.

```
printf("Enter the number of students: ");
scanf("%d", &numStudents);
int studentId [numStudents];

printf("\nEnter the number of courses: ");
    scanf("%d", &numCourses);

char *courseCode[numCourses];
for(i = 0; i < numCourses; i++){
    courseCode[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
}
//I also ran loops to fill the 2 arrays with user input.

int regTable[numStudents][numCourses];
// all items in regTable are initialized to zero 

char cCode[10];
int sID;
int studentIndex = -1;
int courseIndex = -1;

// this portion of code is inside a switch statement

printf("Enter Student ID: ");
  scanf("%d", &sID);
  for(i = 0; i < numStudents; i++){
    if(sID == studentId[i]){
         studentIndex = i;
         break;
    }

    else {
        printf("student Id not found\n");
        break;
    }
}

if(studentIndex >= 0){

printf("Enter Course ID: ");
    scanf("%s", cCode);

    for(i = 0; i < numCourses; i++){
        if(strcmp(cCode, courseCode[i]) == 0){
            courseIndex = i;
        }
    else{
        printf("course Id not found\n");
        break;
    }
    }
    if(courseIndex >= 0){
    regTable[studentIndex][courseIndex] = 1;
    }
}

break;
```

Comment: You break out of the loop after testing the first entry in the list. Instead you could for instance use a variable outside the loop that you set to the found index (if any) and only print the error if the entry wasn't found.

Comment: If you had used a debugger to step through the code, you would have found the problem immidiately and had seen that the program flow was not as you intended: start learning how to use a debugger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(sID == studentId[i]){
     studentIndex = i;
     break;
}

else {
    printf("student Id not found\n");
    break; <--- Remove this
}
```

You break out of the foor loop whether you find a match or not. You should not break when you don't find a student Id and let the next iteration of the loop happen